# RegExp in Zapier not returning any values

Tags: regex, string, zapier

I'm trying to extract some values from discord message in [Zapier](https://zapier.com/).
The content of the message should look somewhat like this (almost like YAML):

```yaml
channel: <#1234567890123456789>
as: Bot nicname
image: http://example.com/
content:
Hello, world!
```

Where `image` and `as` fields are optional.

I have created 2 regular expressions to fulfill this task:

Python:

```py
import re
r = re.compile(r"(?:channel:)? ?<#(?P<channel>\d+)>\n+(?:as: ?(?P<as>.+)\n+)?(:?image: ?(?P<image>.+)\n+)?content:\n*(?P<content>[\s\S]+)")
```

JS:

```js
let r = /(?:channel:)? ?<#(?<channel>\d+)>\n+(?:as: ?(?<as>.+)\n+)?(?:image: ?(?<image>.+)\n+)?content:\n*(?<content>[\s\S]+)/;
```

### What I tried:

Testing regexes in [regexr](https://regexr.com/5k0kb) and [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3Achannel%3A)%3F%20%3F%3C%23(%3FP%3Cchannel%3E%5Cd%2B)%3E%5Cn%2B(%3F%3Aas%3A%20%3F(%3FP%3Cas%3E.%2B)%5Cn%2B)%3F(%3A%3Fimage%3A%20%3F(%3FP%3Cimage%3E.%2B)%5Cn%2B)%3Fcontent%3A%5Cn*(%3FP%3Ccontent%3E%5B%5Cs%5CS%5D%2B)&test_string=channel%3A%20%3C%231234567890123456%3E%0Aas%3A%20bot%20nickname%0Aimage%3A%20http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fabc%3Fimage%3D234%0Acontent%3A%0AHello%2C%20world!&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). Both work fine for me.

Then I entered them into Zapier:

- [In the Text->Formatter by Zapier->Extract pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y35rt.png) - returns `_matched: false`
- [In the Run Python field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvdwi.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRMhW.png) from the python code:

```
    groups: null
    id: <ID>
    runtime_meta:
    memory_used_mb: 57
    duration_ms: 3
    logs:
    1. re.compile('(?:channel:)? ?<#(?P<channel>\\d+)>\\n+(?:as: ?(?P<nick>.+)\\n+)?(:?image: ?(?P<image>.+)\\n+)?content:\\n*(?P<content>[\\s\\S]+)')
    2. 'channel: <#1234567890123456> \nas: bot nickname\ncontent:\nHello, world!'
    3. None
```

(and later in the Run JavaScript with similar result)

### What works (somewhat):

When trying to debug it i removed `image` part of the regexp (in the Text->Extract expression):

```
(?:channel:)? ?<#(?P<channel>\d+)>\n+(?:as: ?(?P<as>.+)\n+)?content:\n*(?P<content>[\s\S]+)
```

With the input:

```yaml
channel: <#1234567890123456>
as: INFO
content:
Hello, world!
```

And the result was as expected:

```
output:
0: 1234567890123456
1: INFO
2: Hello, world!
_end: 68
_matched: true
_start: 0
as: INFO
channel: 1234567890123456
content: Hello, world!
```

---

Any help with getting it to work is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure there are no more than 1 or other spaces at the image part? `(?:channel:)? ?<#(?P<channel>\d+)>\n+(?:as:[^\S\r\n]*(?P<as>.+)\n+)?(:?image:[^\S\r\n]*(?P<image>.+)\n+)?content:\n*(?P<content>[\s\S]+)` https://regex101.com/r/mxrs0Z/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I've checked your regexp and it also was not matched.
What do you mean by 1 or other spaces?
I inserted code that prints the (python) repr() of the content given to the formatter, it was:
`channel: <#12345678901234567> \nas: This is test\nimage: http://www.example.com/\ncontent:\nHello, world!`

Comment: Because `\` ?`\` matches either 0 or ` space. I think there is also a space after `> ` Can you try https://regex101.com/r/wCKAta/1

Comment: This is it! At least for the last input it worked! I'm gonna check other ones and let you know. You can post this as an answer and if it works I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Did it work out?

Comment: Yes it did! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match 0 or more whitespaces except newline using `[^\S\r\n]*`. Use `\s*` to match 0+ times any whitespace char including a newline.

Using  `?` optionally matches a single space.

Depending on the string that you want to match, you can determine to match spaces on the same line, or if it is also accepted to cross newlines.

You might update the pattern to:

```
(?:channel:)?[^\S\r\n]*<#(?P<channel>\d+)>\s*\n(?:as:[^\S\r\n]*(?P<as>.+)\n+)?(:?image:[^\S\r\n]*(?P<image>.+)\n+)?content:\n*(?P<content>[\s\S]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BTRV0H/1)